# How could I copy the same directory multiple times but with a different name?

Tags: directory, cp

I have a directory called 400K that has some files in it, I want to copy this directory multiple times but with different names. 
I want something like: 
cp -r 400K 500K 600K 700K

I was considering using a for loop and run a shell script, but I don't know how to start!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi here is a script you can use:

```
#!/bin/sh

DIR_TO_COPY="400K"

for var in "$@"
do
      echo "Copying $DIR_TO_COPY to $var ..."
      cp -rf $DIR_TO_COPY $var
done
```

let's name it toto.sh
and don't forget to run:

`chmod 755 toto.sh`

to run it:

`./toto.sh 500K 600K 700K`

Answer (score 0):

Use xargs:

```
echo 500K 600K 700K| xargs -n1 cp -r 400K
```